# Can't assign to literal with "for" loop

Tags: python

I am creating a Yahtzee program in Python. This function is meant to carry out the action that the user chooses (the user inputs a number, and it chooses the appropriate list item). I just got to the section about adding the total of one number set (the top part of a Yahtzee card with the ones, twos, etc.). I made a loop that adds one to the score for every `1` found in list `dicevalues` (a random list of "rolled dice" numbers; declared earlier in program).

I am getting the error on the `for 1 in dicevalues:` line. It says `SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal`. I looked up this error, but I'm not making sense of it. What I interpret here is that the program would run the code in the `for` block for every value `1` in `dicevalues`, but I'm not quite sure if you can use the `for` loop in that way.

```
def choiceAction():
  if options[choice] == "Chance (score total of dice).":
    global score
    score += (a + b + c + d + e)
  if options[choice] == "YAHTZEE!":
    score += 50
  if options[choice] == "Large straight":
    score += 40
  if options[choice] == "Small straight.":
    score += 30
  if options[choice] == "Four of a kind (total dice score).":
    score += (a + b + c + d + e)
  if options[choice] == "Three of a kind (total dice score).":
    score += (a + b + c + d + e)
  if options[choice] == "Full house.":
    score += 25
  if options[choice] == "Add all ones.":
    for 1 in dicevalues: # <-- SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
      score += 1
```

Is it possible that for some reason `1` cannot be in the `for` declaration?

Comment: You used the digit "1" instead of a variable name. Variable names **must** begin with a letter or underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The error

When you write `for x in dicevalues:` you iterate over `dicevalues` and put each element in the variable `x`, so `x` can not be replaced with `1`. This is why you get the error `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`.

## The solution(s)

Here are several solutions to perform what you want:

```
dicevalues = [2, 1, 3, 6, 4 ,1, 2, 1, 6]

# 1. Classic 'for' loop to iterate over dicevalues and check if element is equal to 1
score = 0
for i in dicevalues:
    if i == 1:
        score += 1
print(score) # 3

# 2. Comprehension to get only the elements equal to 1 in dicevalues, and sum them
score = 0
score += sum(i for i in dicevalues if i == 1)
print(score) # 3

# 3. The 'count()' method to count the number of elements equal to 1 in dicevalues
score = 0
score += dicevalues.count(1)
print(score) # 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the items in `dicevalues` you can use a placeholder

```
for _ in dicevalues:
```

Comment: But I want to test for the number of instances of the number "1" in `dicevalues`. Like if `dicevalues = [1, 4, 3, 1, 2]`, detect that `1` occurs twice and assign two points to `score`.

Comment: @connectyourcharger then the `for` is entirely wrong. Don't you just want `score += dicevalues.count(1)`? `for x in y:` assigns each item from `y`, in turn, to the name `x`, so a literal as `x` makes no sense.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I will implement that and accept your answer.

Comment: The comment from jonrshape is an answer, but I think the post is not really an answer.